# Ipopt in pyomo with anaconda

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, pyomo, glpk, ipopt

I tried to run a simple code using ipopt in my anaconda after succesfully installation of Coopr, pyomo, glpk and ipopt in my new environment with two different versions of python, 3.9 and 3.11:

```
#SolverFactory('glpk').solve(model).write()
SolverFactory('ipopt').solve(model).write()
```

WHEN I use glpk just as above, it is wonderful, the optimal solution comes and beautiful graphs are shown.
But when I use ipopt just as above, then it comes the nightmare:

The error was:

```
WARNING: Could not locate the 'ipopt' executable, which is required for solver
ipopt
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File c:\users\acbba\anaconda3\envs\pyomo_projects_optimization\scripts\ifac_paper_nlp_fpso_2024.py:1711
    SolverFactory('ipopt').solve(model).write()

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\base\solvers.py:533 in solve
    self.available(exception_flag=True)

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\solver\shellcmd.py:141 in available
    raise ApplicationError(msg % self.name)

ApplicationError: No executable found for solver 'ipopt'
```

What should I do? I was working in the Spyder and also in the Jupyter, but the error remains.
I have saw plenty of videos in the youtube people using just like this, but it is not working.

Tip: even downloading ipopt in my conda env, I also downloaded ipopt.exe and put it in the PATH in the address C:\ipopt\bin.

I also tried the following line of code:

```
SolverFactory('ipopt', executable= 'C:\Users\acbba\anaconda3\envs\PYOMO_PROJECTS_OPTIMIZATION\ipopt.exe').solve(model).write()
```

But it still gives an error:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Comment: Try escaping your backslashes \\

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  When using paths in python under a Windows platform, always either escape the ```\``` (i.e. 'C:\\Users\\acbba\\...') or use raw strings.  i.e.  ```r'c:\Users\....'```.

Comment: when using backslashes \\, the following error occurs:
ERROR: Solver (ipopt) returned non-zero return code (3221225501)
ERROR: Solver log: Ipopt 3.11.1:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

    results = SolverFactory('ipopt', executable= 'C:\\Users\\acbba\\anaconda3\\envs\\PYOMO_PROJECTS_OPTIMIZATION\\Scripts\\ipopt.exe').solve(model).write()


Solver (ipopt) did not exit normally